# Storybook Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') error with nextjs

Tags: next.js, storybook

Trying to get storybook working with nextjs but getting this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
> at http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:4049:37
> at http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:18699:12
> at http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:18757:12
> at http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:4094:20
> at unboundStoryFn (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:18398:12)
> at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:89911:18)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:93675:13)
> at beginWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:95188:16)
> at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:101027:14)
> at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_preview_js-generated-config-entry_js-node_module-16c9e3.iframe.bundle.js:100161:12)

// main.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    // '../stories/**/*.stories.mdx',
    // '../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-scss',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      },

      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,

        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

// preview.js

```
import * as NextImage from 'next/image';
import '../styles/globals.scss';
import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context';
import { withNextRouter } from 'storybook-addon-next-router';

const BREAKPOINTS_INT = {
  xs: 375,
  sm: 600,
  md: 900,
  lg: 1200,
  xl: 1536,
};

const customViewports = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(BREAKPOINTS_INT).map(([key, val], idx) => {
    console.log(val);
    return [
      key,
      {
        name: key,
        styles: {
          width: `${val}px`,
          height: `${(idx + 5) * 10}vh`,
        },
      },
    ];
  })
);

// Allow Storybook to handle Next's <Image> component
const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => <OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized />,
});

export const decorators = [withNextRouter];

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
  },
  viewport: { viewports: customViewports },
};
```

sorry for dumping whole config here.

found this on google search but I don't even have `@storybook/addon-a11y addon`
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue and I think the problem was with the `@storybook/preset-scss`. This is the working `main.js` and `preview.js` respectively:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../stories/welcome.stories.tsx',
    '../stories/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    // '@storybook/addon-actions',
    'storybook-addon-next-router',
    'storybook-addon-next',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    // '@storybook/preset-scss',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      },

      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },

  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,

        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

```
import * as NextImage from 'next/image';
// import '../styles/globals.scss';
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../styles/globals.scss';

import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context'; // next 12

const BREAKPOINTS_INT = {
  xs: 375,
  sm: 600,
  md: 900,
  lg: 1200,
  xl: 1536,
};

const customViewports = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(BREAKPOINTS_INT).map(([key, val], idx) => {
    console.log(val);
    return [
      key,
      {
        name: key,
        styles: {
          width: `${val}px`,
          height: `${(idx + 5) * 10}vh`,
        },
      },
    ];
  })
);

// Allow Storybook to handle Next's <Image> component
const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => <OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized />,
});

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
    // foo: 'this-is-a-global-override',
  },
  viewport: { viewports: customViewports },
};
```